# Deserialize string by class name

Tags: c#, reflection, deserialization

Let's say I have a Value that is deserialized from a class.

```
public class MyValue
{
    public string MyPropertyA { get; set; }
    public string MyPropertyB { get; set; }
    public string DeserializationClass { get; } = typeof(MyValue).Name;
}
```

I serialize this using `JsonConvert` class. `MyValue` class has a property `DeserializationClass` that should be used as info from which class the string was serialized from. In other words, when I deserialize the string into an object, this property serves as info which class should be used to deserialize the string. However, I am kinda stuck here as I am not sure how to get back the class from the string. Can anybody help me here?

```
public class Program
{
    void Main()
    {
        var serialized = Serialize();
        var obj = Deserialize(serialized);
    }

    string Serialize()
    {
        var objValue = new MyValue { MyPropertyA="Something", MyPropertyB="SomethingElse" };
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject<MyClass>(value);
    }

    object Deserialize(string serialized)
    {            
        //How to deserialize based on 'DeserializationClass' property in serialized string?
        return = JsonConvert.Deserialize<???>(serialized);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Modified example to make it more clear what I need as I don't have access to objValue when I need to deserialize the string.

Comment: You probably want to use `TypeNameHandling.All` instead of all this: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm#TypeNameHandling

Answer (score 3):

probably you might need to use JsonSerializerSettings.
What you might need to do is

```
 JsonSerializerSettings setting = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
            };
```

and then while serializing use this setting.

```
 var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objValue,setting);
```

this will give you Json like this

> ```
> {"$type":"WPFDatagrid.MyValue, WPFDatagrid","MyPropertyA":"Something","MyPropertyB":"SomethingElse","DeserializationClass":"MyValue"}
> ```

from this you can find the name of the class used it to actually get your type.

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload

If your `Type` is in form of a Namespace, you can obtain the type from a string representation:

```
Type objValueType = Type.GetType("Namespace.MyValue, MyAssembly");
object deserialized = JsonConvert.Deserialize(objValueType, serialized);
```

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that I don't have access to objValue when I am deserializing the string. So I don't know what type was used to serialize to the string.